# New Outlook API (2015) mail add-in send event

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-restapi, outlook-web-addins

Does the new Microsoft Outlook API, which enables development of Outlook addins for cross platform, have the ability to trigger an event off the user clicking the send button?

I currently have an Outlook VSTO addin that uses the Application.ItemSend event to check an email for specific content and present the user with a popup asking them if they still want to send or not.  This is only compatible with Outlook 2007-16 on Windows though, and I was hoping the new API might enable me to build something similar for Outlook on Mac/mobile/web, but I haven't found any examples or documentation on this particular event trigger yet.

[Link to Outlook API](https://dev.outlook.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no such event. It will most likely be added in the future from what I hear...

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, do you know if there has been any mention of timescale for when they will add it?

Comment: I am not aware of any dates, but I do know it is a high priority for them.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko - Did you see the new functionality? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins?tabs=windows

Comment: Yes, it was added a while back.

Answer (score 3):

Some [support for handling a "send" event](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/outlook/outlook-on-send-addins) was recently added for Outlook Add-ins.

There are several limitations, so be sure to read all the documentation. In particular, this is currently only supported in the Web version of Outlook, and the send event feature cannot be used in any add-ins that will be published in the Office Store.

Comment: We are writing a COM Add-In that interacts with our database to manage information associated with Meetings.  As such, we are currently listening for Folder change/move events so we make sure to delete or edit our related info.  Is there any way to do this with the Outlook Add-Ins API?