# Do Outlook Add-ins API support event listeners?

Tags: javascript, email, outlook, office365, outlook-web-addins

I am planning to write an Outlook Add-in and I was wondering if there was a way to listen to events, such as the "send button". In practice, I'd like to manipulate the body when the user presses the send button and so, even before sending the email.

From what I have seen, the only way to do this, is to create a button, such as "manipulate", and attach an event on the on-click. It's feasible, but it's quite annoying if you have to do it every single time you send an email.

Further, how does Outlook run the add-ins? In compose mode, if I do have a:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync
```

Is this run whenever I type a new letter in my body or when I send the message? I am a bit confused.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33571914/new-outlook-api-2015-mail-add-in-send-event) could slightly be a duplicate. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot attach listeners on DOM elements of the parent window of your iFrame (where your add-in lives). So you cannot hack the behavior of Outlook Web Access buttons.

It is important to note that the new Office web addins generation are less intrusive than old desktop addins. Indeed, with VSTO for example, one does have access to the entire Outlook Object Model for better or for worse. Here is [a blog post](https://keluro.com/2015/12/08/new-generation-addins-office/) that I wrote on the subject.

The solution you describe seems the suitable way to do what you want. In addition, let me stress out that its a good thing that web addins framework do not let you change the content of an email without user consent.

Keep in mind that Office.js offers you the possibility to communicate with EWS API which is very useful when something is not available directly from the Office.js API. [See this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn148008.aspx).

Comment: So there's no confusion: EWS tokens are only required when you need to do server-based calls to Exchange; calling mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync doesn't require these tokens, but you have a smaller subset of operations that are supported. But Benoit probably knows all this already ;-)

Comment: @EricLegault, you are right I should not mention the token only the fact that you can dialog with EWS (I have edited the answer). Remark also that makeEwsRequestAsync needs a ReadWriteMailbox permission this implies that only an administrator can install your addin.

Comment: All users can install web add-ins of any permission level without requiring elevated permissions.  They are after all the "admin" of their own mailboxes.

Comment: Yes you are right, I have just tested to be sure. I thought I read it somewhere on the msdn... However, the new documentation seems ok https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161087.aspx#olowa15conagave_permmodelreadwrite

Comment: Ok, so basically it's impossible to activate an add-in and let it work on the background before sending any email whatsoever? I am trying to replicate a chrome plugin that has exactly this behaviour. It's quite annoying if the user has to push a button every single time.

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this? I can clearly see that Sidekick by Hubspot does it, but I don't think they use Outlook add-ins new api. :(

Comment: it depends on what you want to achieve. As I said, you do have access to the mailbox web api... You can use it to send email on background for example...

Answer (score 1):

Regarding "*Is this run whenever I type a new letter in my body or when I send the message?*"

By my experimentation it will return the new body content every few seconds (close to ~20 seconds), even if you call Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync every second.

I don't know why this interval of refresh exists, it's not documented AFAIK, and why it's not refreshed in every letter as happens in VSTO add-in.

The only (strange) method I found to get it refreshed in real time is if the user presses the task pane.

I guess we'll have to wait for something like [excel js api events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/excel/excel-add-ins-events).

Comment: Have there been any updates on this in Outlook?  We have a COM API that we would love to transfer to Outlook js API, but since we have items related to Meetings, and thus need to delete or edit them when the meeting is edited or deleted, including through Folder events, it does not seem possible in Outlook js API.